# Pass eloquent method as a parameters

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I trouble to pass `eloquent` methods as a parameter.

Here is my method,

```
public function getPayment($paymentId, $eloquentMethod)
{
    if (!empty($orderId)) {
        return DB::connection('my_db')->table('payment')->{$eloquentMethod}();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It is working properly if i pass `$this->getPayment('1', 'get')`

But it is not working if i pass `$this->getPayment('1', 'pluck("payment_id")')`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `$eloquentMethod = 'get'`?

Comment: Try: `$eloquentMethod = 'get'` and then use `return DB::connection('my_db')->table('payment')->{$eloquentMethod}();`

Comment: @tyteen4a03 yes but with parameter.

Comment: @HirenGohel yes but how to pass parameter like : `pluck('id')`

Answer (score 1):

How much possibilities do you have for `$eloquentMethod` ?
If many possibilities such as "get","first"..etc then you can make:

```
public function getPayment($paymentId, $eloquentMethod = 'get()')
{
    if (!empty($orderId)) {
        switch ($eloquentMethod) {
            case "get":
                return DB::connection('my_db')->table('payment')->get();
                break;
            case "first":
                return DB::connection('my_db')->table('payment')->first();
                break;
            case default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```